# Deleting multiple Outlook tasks

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I want to delete multiple `Outlook.TaskItem`. Tasks which are to be deleted are stored in a `List`. I iterate over each item in the list and delete each outlook task one by one in the following manner:

```cs
resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
item = resultItems.GetFirst();
Outlook.MailItem mail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
List<Outlook.TaskItem> taskList = new List<Outlook.TaskItem>();
do
{
   if (item != null)
    {if (item is Outlook.TaskItem)
        {taskItem = item as Outlook.TaskItem;
         if (taskItem.CreationTime >= date)
          {  log.Info("Attaching task : " + taskItem.Subject + " created at 
             " + taskItem.CreationTime);
             taskList.Add(taskItem);
             mail.Attachments.Add(taskItem);
          }                        
         }
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
               item = resultItems.GetNext();
     }
 }while (item != null);
 foreach (Outlook.TaskItem tItem in taskList)
    {
        log.Info("Deleting task with subject :" + tItem.Subject);
        tItem.Delete();
    }
```

But it throws this exception:
`The COM object has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used`

Stacktrace:

```cs
System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._TaskItem.get_Subject()
   at TMTimeCapture.ThisAddIn.DeleteMyTasks(MAPIFolder folder)
```

I tried to add `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tItem)` after `tItem.Delete();` that doesn't help either.

As per the logs, this exception occurs even before the log of first iteration is generated.
Can someone suggest where am I going wrong and what should be the correct way of deleting multiple tasks?

**Edit 2**: Before looping over the tasks to delete them, I'm iterating over the same list and attaching the tasks to a mailItem and sending that mail. I doubt if the prior iteration and use of `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);` in it is causing issue in the next loop where tasks are deleted. I've updated the code. Please suggest something as per the updated context.

Comment: Do you get that error on the very first item? Or the subsequent one? Are you sure you don't have dupes in the list?

Comment: I'm getting this error on the very first item. Because for every iteration I'm logging the subject line but no subject line is printed. I'm sure there's no duplicates, there are all unique.

Comment: Make sure you don't clean up the items in the list with Marshal.ReleaseComObject calls.

Comment: I'm quiet not sure if i understand cleaning up the items using Marshal.ReleaseComObject() . I'll share the whole context with code as I'm using the same list for attaching those tasks in a mail.

Comment: I've updated the question, do you think the first iteration where I'm attaching the tasks to the mail is causing the problem? In the first loop, I'm just adding adding the tasks to ```taskList``` and using that list in next loop.

Comment: Well, you did use Marshal.ReleaseComObject - so the object is no longer valid. That is what the error tells you.

Comment: Okay, after removing ```Marshal.ReleaseComObject``` from every where, the code is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides removing the call to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, you can instead use `List<string>` and store the `TaskItem.EntryID` property. When you need to delete the tasks, you can open them first using `Application.Session.GetItemFromID` before calling `TaskItem.Delete`.

Comment: I'm not well versed with inbuilt outlook function, but I've a doubt about the suggested method for task deletion. Could you please clear it? Will not it be more time consuming to fetch each task by using task's id in ```Application.Session.GetItemFromID```  than already having a reference to task and directly deleting them?

Comment: In an online profile, if you open more than 255 items, you will receive an error. The idea is to keep the number of opened objects to a minimum and only open them on demand.